# D3.js non linear scale line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I need to produce a line chart, the y axis domain runs from 1.01 to 1000.
At the following points in the axis the value of a tick changes:

- 1.01 to 2, tick = 0.01
- 2 to 3, tick = 0.02
- 3 to 4, tick = 0.05
- 4 to 6, tick = 0.1
- 6 to 10, tick = 0.2
- 10 to 20, tick = 0.5
- 20 to 30, tick = 1
- 30 to 50, tick = 2
- 50 to 100, tick = 5
- 100 to 1000, tick = 10

In the chart image all the paths above x = 4.0 are twice as long as they should be.  I have been researching non linear scales without much success.

---

```
const svg = d3.select('#line_chart_svg');
const width = +svg.attr('width');
const height = +svg.attr('height');

const margin = { top: 20, bottom: 30, right: 20, left: 50 };
const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const render = priceTimeData => {

const xValue = d => d.timeStamp;
const yValue = d => d.price;

const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(priceTimeData, xValue))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .nice();

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(priceTimeData, yValue))
    .range([innerHeight, 0]);
    console.log(yScale)

// Declare g and adjust size
const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

// Setup xAxis 
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
const xAxisG = g.append('g').call(xAxis)
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`);

// Setup yAxis
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    .tickSize(-innerWidth);
const yAxisG = g.append('g').call(yAxis);

const lineGenerator = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(xValue(d)))
    .y(d => yScale(yValue(d)));

g.append('path')
.attr('class', 'line_path')
    .attr('d', lineGenerator(priceTimeData));

}

const priceTimeData = d3.csv('data/priceTime.csv').then(data => {
data.forEach(d => {
    d.price = +d.price
    d.timeStamp = new Date(d.timeStamp);
})
render(data)
});
```

---

[image: Line Chart]

Comment: hi - did you want the ticks spaced evenly on the axis (so you need a log scale), or did you want a linear scale, with the ticks getting wider apart?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would like the tick spacing to vary.

Answer (score 0):

D3 won't do this, unless you have different scales per period.

I would create the tick values manually, like so:

```
var tickValues = [
      {"lower": 1.01, "upper": 2, "interval": 0.01},
      {"lower": 2, "upper": 3, "interval": 0.02},
      {"lower": 3, "upper": 4, "interval": 0.05},
      {"lower": 4, "upper": 6, "interval": 0.1},
      {"lower": 6, "upper": 10, "interval": 0.2},
      {"lower": 10, "upper": 20, "interval": 0.5},
      {"lower": 20, "upper": 30, "interval": 1},
      {"lower": 30, "upper": 50, "interval": 2},
      {"lower": 50, "upper": 100, "interval": 5},
      {"lower": 100, "upper": 1000, "interval": 10}
    ]

    let tickArray = []
    let currentTickValue = 0

    tickValues.forEach(function(t){

      currentTickValue = t.lower

      for (var i = t.lower; i < t.upper; i = i + t.interval) {

        currentTickValue = currentTickValue + t.interval
        currentTickValue = (Math.floor(currentTickValue * 100))/100
        tickArray.push(currentTickValue)

      }
    })

    let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        //etc

    let yAxis = d3.axisRight(yScale)
        .tickValues(tickValues)
```